# Joomla 2.5 Load custom field in components layout fatal error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Im trying to load custom field in my backend component default view (default.php):

```
JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');
$productType = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('ProductType',false);

$productTypeOptions = $productType->getOptions();
```

But I get a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in xxx\libraries\joomla\form\fields\list.php on line 89
```

When I load this custom field into the form, everything works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to put field type in `JFormHelper::loadFieldType` not the field name

Comment: @Tornado: Im putting field type. ProductType is field type:
protected $type = 'ProductType';

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are adding the correct path to the fields

Comment: I modified the include path to: 
JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'models'.DS.'fields');     

But I do get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$productType->getOptions()` function, 
Try removing:
`$options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to expand my fellow above idea but it seemed an inappropiate edit, I put it here then:

This worked for me. In your getOptions, if you have something like the getOptions found here (http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_custom_filters_to_component_admin), you´ll have this line:

$options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);

This is the one that makes the error. Why? Well, I´m not sure. If you see the related file, you´ll find this:

foreach ($this->element->children() as $option)

So the problem is that you are calling children() on the model parent that it seems is not initialized. Why the array_merge is needed? Is discussed here (http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=626&t=782877)

My explanation is more like a dirty blind patch, but hope it helps to move forward.