# Use form field type of Joomla outside XML

Tags: xml, joomla, components, formfield

I'm developping a component. Inside a tmpl of my administrator component, I want to use the form field type from this page => https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field

For example, I want to use this one => https://docs.joomla.org/Menuitem_form_field_type

Is it possible ?

I use the latest version of Joomla (3.4.3)

Comment: You can use any form field type as per your use which listed here https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field

Comment: I think your question is a bit confusing. WHat do you mean by "outside XML"?  You can always instantiate a JForm and use an xml string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use something like this (although this doc is for custom field): https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type#Not_linked_with_a_form

Comment: It's what I'm searching, now I'm searching how to get menuitem options.

Comment: @harkor It could be difficult, because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861563/joomla-2-5-load-custom-field-in-components-layout-fatal-error (check irbian answer)

Comment: the stackoverflow question created in 2012 and that's concern custom field type... I think his problem solved by Joomla now.

Comment: @harkor Actually no, there is still the same issue for Joomla 3. There is still code: $groups = array_merge(parent::getGroups(), $groups); in menutiem field class declaration. Take: $mitem = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('menuitem', true); and try to render it ($mitem->renderField();)

Comment: the "menuitem" field doesn't concern the fields in the JFormHelper, it's in another folder. I don't know if it's really the same thing.